# The conversion of the varchar value overflowed an int column with sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The conversion of the varchar value '82332617284' overflowed an int column.

I have data such as

```
BreakID = 82332617284
```

Thus I have line of code to pull out the number only, so it looks like the following:

```
join dst.ExceptionsDST d on f.BreakOwnerId = replace(substring(d.dstbreakid,charindex('=',d.dstbreakid) + 1,99),' ','')
```

What do I need to do in order to just pull the numbers and do the join without getting this error?

It is definitely something with this part

`replace(substring(d.dstbreakid,charindex('=',d.dstbreakid) + 1,99),' ','')`

Comment: CAST(yourcolumn as BIGINT)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If you're doing a `JOIN` on that expression it's going to make it very difficult for the Server; as the expression isn't SARGable. Personally, I'd suggest making the value a `PERSISTED` computed column and then performing your `JOIN` on the new (computed) column. If you then index accordingly (you can put an index on a `PERSISTED` column) you'll probably find a decent performance increase.

Comment: The question is: does `f` contain the value `82332617284`? It does not if it is an int.

Comment: You should probably be using `numeric`/`decimal` for the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TRY_CONVERT` to avoid this error:

```
SELECT dstbreakid, TRY_CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(d.dstbreakid, CHARINDEX('=', d.dstbreakid) + 1, 99))
FROM (VALUES
    ('x = 82332617284 '),
    ('x = 823326172 ')
) d(dstbreakid)
```

Output:

```
| dstbreakid      | (No column name) |
|-----------------|------------------|
| x = 82332617284 | NULL             |
| x = 823326172   | 823326172        |
```

If `f.BreakOwnerId` is of datatype `int` then it cannot contain the value `823326172`.

Comment: I noticed that the table for the column  f.BreakOwnerId is indeed INT  , so you are right  - seems someone hookwinked me a bit.   I'm looking at the data etc..   thx

Answer (score 1):

`int` is too small a datatype for your number. You'll have to get rid of so big numbers, or change the column datatype to `bigint`.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that your value is bigint. Int datatype can't hold it.

For Example, I'm trying to insert your value #t which is int data type. Will end up with same error

```
create table #t (id int)
insert into #t values(82332617284)
```

but this wont error out because it is bigint.

```
create table #t1 (id bigint)
insert into #t1 values(82332617284)
```

So if you can change your code like below will help,

```
join dst.ExceptionsDST d on  f.BreakOwnerId = CAST(replace(substring(d.dstbreakid,charindex('=',d.dstbreakid) + 1,99),' ','') as Bigint)
```

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to bigint.